# ISO 8601 with Daylight Savings

Tags: datetime, iso8601

My API is representing time to clients using ISO 8601. We have a feature where we want to display which timezone it was from. By purely storing the timezone offset, we are loosing track of that detail.

ie, Utah and Arizona observe MST `-06:00` for half of the year and Utah switches to MDT `-07:00` for the other half. Our current solution is to determine if the date was during daylight savings and to use `*DT` timezones during and `*ST` otherwise, but ISO 8601 dates from Arizona would result in Pacific Daylight Time.

Is there a way to specify whether daylight savings is being observed in an ISO 8601 format? Like `2016-01-11T13:00:04Z DST0` or something similar?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267(v=vs.110).aspx: "First, date and time values are not tightly coupled with the time zones to which they belong. As a result, unless your application provides some mechanism for linking a date and time with its associated time zone, it is easy for a particular date and time value to become disassociated from its time zone." - So you'd have to implement it yourself, or use a library.

Comment: If you are using Z you are specifying the time is UTC, so convert as applicable depending on date. If you want to know which timezone the user had when inserting that date, I guess that should need to go to a different field.

Answer (score 6):

ISO 8601 glides quite smoothly (and misleadingly) between the terms "Time Zone" and "UTC Offset".

For the purpose of referencing a globally unique moment, a representation like "Thh:mm:ssZ+01:00" works perfectly in the sense that:

- it designates a *unique* point on the UTC scale,
- it is *agnostic* whether the originator is located in Z+01, or in Z+00
  during DST.

If you want to convey, *in addition*, the originator's *locality* then a suitable location field can be appended *outside* of the 8601 structure. There is no need to include location in a time field.

Personally, I'd like to see "Time **Zone**" banished from ISO 8601.

Comment: Note that a timestamp with time zone should either use `Z` to denote UTC or add `±hh` or `±hh:mm` to indicate the time zone offset from UTC.  It does not suggest a `Z` between the time and the zone information, though it would make some sense if it did.  See pages 17-19 of ISO 8601:2004 for the specification of the notation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a new revision of ISO 8601:2004 is in preparation, and that it has been split into two parts, ISO 8601-1:201x (matching the current standard) and ISO 8601-2:201x (a new section, dealing with a variety of extensions to the basic standard, such as uncertain or unspecified times, or years with more than 4 digits, etc).  A Google search on 'iso 8601 pdf' turns up [Draft ISO 8601-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0038_iso_wd_8601-1_2016-02-16.pdf) and [Draft ISO 8601-2](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0039_iso_wd_8601-2_2016-02-16.pdf).  Since these date from 2016, but the ANSI web store still provides ISO 8601:2004 (for a fee), they are not yet the standard — the standard is still ISO 8601:2004.

Neither the standard nor the drafts allows for anything other than a numeric time zone offset from UTC (`±1030` or `±10:30`, for a fictitious example) or `Z` (denoting UTC, aka Zulu time — because letter Z is called Zulu in the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)).

Consequently, there is no direct guidance available from ISO 8601.

Time zones are a continually contentious subject, and there is nothing simple about them.  For example, in February 2018, the state of Florida passed legislation such that it will remain on 'daylight saving time' around the year; whether this will be allowed remains to be seen. IANA hosts (but does not directly manage) the 'Olson' Time Zone Database (named after its original creator, A. D. Olson).  You can find information on the TZDB at https://www.iana.org/time-zones.  The current version of the database is available for download, and there are two mailing lists, one for announcements (a few times a year) and one for ongoing discussions (most days, often multiple messages in a day).  The [Unicode Consortium](https://unicode.org) also has the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (Common Locale Data Repository) which also deals with time zone names in passing (it deals with many other aspects of locale too, and they're its primary goal, not time zones).

Even within Arizona, things are not simple.  Most of Arizona does not use summer time (daylight saving time), but the Navajo nation does use summer time, except that the area within the Navajo nation for the Hopi nation does not use summer time.  Even geolocating a point where the time applies may not help.  There are cities where two different populations use different time zone offsets from UTC, even though there is no distinct area for the two offsets.  You pretty much have to know which time zone should be considered to apply to the date/time value you are recording, and there is no 100% reliable way to know that.  (Suppose someone from California is travelling in Europe and sets up a meeting with team members in New York, London, Rome, Sydney, and Kolkata — which time zone applies to the meeting?)

Comment: You might find some material of interest at [UTC is enough for everyone, right?](https://zachholman.com/talk/utc-is-enough-for-everyone-right), and perhaps at [The Future of UTC](http://futureofutc.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is getting old, the below I hope will at least spur on conversation and ideas.

So, The basis of this question is in my opinion the problem with ISO 8601, it cannot carry the necessary information to assist in daylight savings conversions.

I was faced with a similar issue a while back and hand many "constructive" conversations with colleagues around how to best solve the issue of date recorded inside daylight savings but viewed from timezone without daylight savings... we always kept circling back to ISO 8601 being the lord all mighty for solving date and time transport but it never solved the daylight savings issue.

The conclusion was similar to what many people end up deciding on and that was to use ISO 8601 for date and time with the offset ( even though it was useless ) and then provide an extra piece of data to indicate the timezone in which the date and time belonged. This allowed for client side rendering to provide the timezone along with ISO 8601 to give the actual correct date and time regardless of timezone.

Now, this was not where I wanted to leave this... in fact I was one of few in the discussions that kept poking timezone holes in ISO 8601 when others were convinced the offset was sufficient. Just like you have discovered it does not allow for timezone awareness or accurate conversions to other timezones and as such I deemed ISO 8601 an invalid date and time with timezone transport format.

The following is partially a joke but its also serious when you consider it to be enough to just work... IOS 8601 has a strict format to follow, so does this and when you follow it correctly it just works without flaw...

This page provides detail on the format, along with some silly jokes around planetary support for timezones.
https://github.com/Gitapedia/AltSO-8601

I also have a PHP extended Carbon class that supports parsing and transforming Altso 8601 format.
https://packagist.org/packages/mossengine/alteredcarbon
This package would have been better to plugin to the Carbon package but an extended class was enough to at least show a proof of concept.

It looks like there could be work in play to improve the ISO 8601 format with a revision but I cannot wait that long and feel the offset is useless and can be substituted with the timezone and why do we need all the colons and dashes and Ts and Zs when we can just concatenate the date and time together and it is still readable and smaller to allow for the extra bytes needed to provide timezone.

Next step would be to consider ( if it exists ) supporting shortname timezones or to invent them so that the Altso 8601 format can transport smaller amounts of data with greater insights to the date and time ( particularly timezone )

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to do this well using ISO8601 nor RFC2822. I am storing time in a MySql Database - a time called 'TV Time' in this article https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info. TV Time is a different offset from UTC during Daylight Savings compared to when it is not daylight savings time - but it referred to by my users as the same time. EG: "I start work at 9am" not "I start work at 22:00UTC in summer and at 21:00UTC in Winter".

My solution was to add an additional string column to the database ( I named it 'tzid') and store the text tzid from this list https://unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/zone_tzid.html (and in PHP the DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations () gives a list too). The date time is stored in a mysql DateTime column

Most of the time I pass in the 'TV Time' to my application from the datetime column and it just renders without consequence. If I ever need to compare times across timezones, or work out intervals, I can convert to UTC using the tzid column.